# Loop to display all information in html cards

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am trying to make a flask website which will display a specific amount of information based on results.
I have managed to get the data from the database and I know how to display it on 1 html card, but I cant find a way to display all information based on the length of the array I am passing.
this is the result so far [website][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycqwt.png

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %} Search {% endblock %}
{% block style %}{% endblock %}
{% block body %}

<h1 align="center">Resluts</h1>
<div class="card" id = "element1">
<img src={{url_for('static', filename='pictures/uni.jpg')}} alt="Avatar" style="width:20%">
<div class="container">
<h4><b>Name: {{ name }}</b></h4>
<p>Country: {{ country }}</p>
<p>Major: {{ major }}</p>
<p>Slect and visit: {{ link }}</p>

</div>
<div class="card">
<img src={{url_for('static', filename='pictures/uni.jpg')}} alt="Avatar" style="width:20%">
<div class="container">
<h4><b>Name: {{ name }}</b></h4>
<p>Country: {{ country }}</p>
<p>Major: {{ major }}</p>
<p>Slect and visit: {{ link }}</p>

</div>


<p>Here is my variable: {{ text1 }}</p>


{% endblock %}
```

what I have also tried

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="card" id = "div1">
<img src={{url_for('static', filename='pictures/uni.jpg')}} alt="Avatar" style="width:20%">
<div class="container">
<h4><b>Name: {{ name }}</b></h4>
<p>Country: {{ country }}</p>
<p>Major: {{ major }}</p>
<p>Slect and visit: {{ link }}</p>

</div>
<button onclick="body()">Try it</button>
<script>
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[2],
newdiv = document.createElement('container');   
                 //add an id
body.appendChild(newdiv);                 

 }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to pass the array of results and the length and the magic to happen from there
this is @app.route("/search", methods=["POST", "GET"]) in app.py

```
        if request.method == "POST":
            major = request.form["major"]
            country = request.form["country"]
            price = request.form["price"]
            global universities
            universities = search_universities(country, major, price)
            print(universities)
            if universities != []:
                #for x in universities:
                #   name = x[0]
                #   country = x[1]
                #   major = x[2]
                #   price = x[3]
                #   link = x[4]
                list_length = len(universities)
                return render_template('result.html', text1 = universities, list_length = list_length)
            else:
                return render_template('result.html')
        return render_template('search.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data that you're sending is in the form of an array `text1`. So you need not re-render the same template every time, you simply have to loop through it and set the values accordingly.

For an instance, it should look like this:

```
{% for text in text1 %}
        <h4><b>Name: {{ text[0] }}</b></h4>
        <p>Country: {{ text[1]}}</p>
        <p>Major: {{ text[2] }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Use this one for reference (`text1` is your data that is being passed):

```
<h1 align="center">Resluts</h1>
<div class="card" id = "element1">
<img src={{url_for('static', filename='pictures/uni.jpg')}} alt="Avatar" style="width:20%">
<div class="container">
    {% for text in text1 %}
        <h4><b>Name: {{ text[0] }}</b></h4>
        <p>Country: {{ text[1]}}</p>
        <p>Major: {{ text[2] }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Hope this works for you. Let me know if you've any more doubts.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)